Accessing Private Members of Derived Class through Base Class Pointer with Virtual Function in C++
I have a scenario in C++ where I'm accessing private members of a derived class through a base class pointer, and it seems to work without any errors. Here's a simplified version of the code:
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Shape {
public:
    virtual void calculateArea() {
        cout << "Parent CLASS ";
    }
};

class Rectangle : public Shape {
private:
    void calculateArea() override {
        cout << "Child class";
    }
};

int main() {
    int arraySize = 2;
    Shape *shapes[arraySize]; // Array of Shape pointers

    shapes[0] = new Shape;
    shapes[1] = new Rectangle;

    shapes[1]->calculateArea();

    // Cleanup: Delete dynamically allocated objects
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; ++i) {
        delete shapes[i];
    }

    return 0;
}


I tried accessing the private member of the Rectangle class through a base class pointer and expected it to result in a compilation error or a runtime error due to the access violation of private members. However, to my surprise, the code compiled and executed without any errors, and it printed the expected output. I'm curious about why this behavior occurred, as I expected private members to be inaccessible outside of the class they belong to.

You are accessing it via a Shape pointer, and it's public in Shape. It's usually not a good idea to change access when overriding.

Side notes: in Shape *shapes[arraySize];, arraySize should be const (C++ doesn't support VLAs). Also youd better use std::vector or std::array instead of raw C arrays. And smart pointers instead of raw ones.

Does this answer your question? Overriding public virtual functions with private functions in C++

Also worth noting: delete shape[1]; will call the destructor of Shape but not the destuctor of the Rectangle since you didn't make the base class destructor virtual.

Shape* is a pointer to an object of type Shape; calculateArea is public in Shape. That's all there is to it. Deriving from Shape doesn't change Shape.

There is no access violation error in the code. You need to focus on two main features of cpp. Late binding(RTTI) and static binding (name lookup, context control, access control).
Since you are calling the member function from the base class and its access specifier is public, the static binding control would pass. When the code runs, virtual dispatch will take place and call the derived class's member function.
Therefore, It does not matter if the derived class's member function is private or not when calling with Base class pointer.
